# NFS Mounts/ Failed reboot - Race Condition?

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, boot, fstab

I recently suffered the joy of a server crash (Ubuntu 12.04) and a subsequent failure to reboot.

It appears that the OS attempted to mount the NFS shares in the /etc/fstab file before networking had been loaded by the OS, meaning the OS failed to get past that point in the boot cycle.

My fstab file is correct and this server has been rebooted before, so I can only think this is a race condition?

Is there any way I can mount the directories in the fstab after the OS has booted OR at least do it at the very end of the boot process?

Comment: Are you starting the network at boot with a configuration in /etc/network/interfaces, or connecting with NetworkManager after logging in?

Comment: Starting with config in /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: take a look in http://askubuntu.com/questions/260930/how-can-i-make-the-network-boot-before-mountall-in-12-10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround is to edit `/etc/fstab` to use the `_netdev` mount option.
From mount man page:

> **_netdev**
>                 The filesystem resides on a device that requires network access (used to prevent the system from attempting to mount these
>   filesystems until the network has been enabled  on
>                 the system).

Other possibilities are to use the `soft` or `intr` mount options.

Please note that *all* these options have their drawback, the bigger being the fact the they will skip NFS mount entirely, without trying later.

The real solution probably is to use the **`autofs`** mechanism, for on-demand mounts.

Or, at least, try to mount your NFS share very late in the boot process - maybe using rc.local (or the likes).